# rehshape image to 3 columns matrix matlab vs openCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Here is the matlab code:

```
accum1r = imresize(accum1, n2_points, 'bilinear','AntiAliasing',false);    
time_mean_unsorted = reshape(accum1r, [], 3) ./ n_frames;
```

here is my openCV code

```
    cv::Mat accum1r(x_n2_points, y_n2_points,CV_64FC3);
    cv::resize(_accum1,accum1r,accum1r.size(),0.0,0.0,cv::INTER_LINEAR);

    int newRows = accum1r.rows * accum1r.cols;
    int dims[2] = {newRows,3};    
    cv::Mat planes[] = {cv::Mat::zeros(newRows,1, CV_32F), cv::Mat::zeros(newRows,1, CV_32F), cv::Mat::zeros(newRows,1, CV_32F)};
    cv::split(accum1r,planes);
    planes[0] = planes[0].t();    
    planes[0] = planes[0].reshape(1,2,dims);
    planes[1] = planes[1].t();    
    planes[1] = planes[1].reshape(1,2,dims);
    planes[2] = planes[2].t();    
    planes[2] = planes[2].reshape(1,2,dims);    
    cv::merge(planes,3,accum1r);
    cv::Mat timeMeanUnsorted = accum1r / (double)numberOfFrames;
```

this is the only way I was able to get the same accurate results. I can't get reshape of openCV to do the same functionality as matlab.

when I use reshape matlab does it columns first and openCV does it rows first 
so I need to split my 3D matrix into planes -> transpose them -> reshape them -> join them... this is a little complex..
am I missing something here? can this be done in a simpler way?

Attached  input data is 1920x1088x3 matrix 2 files: accum1,accum2
:http://www.filetolink.com/b2a20a1f73

```
n2_point = [137, 77]
n_nframes = 3
```

Comment: MATLAB is a column-major language, C++ is row-major.

Comment: @IKavanagh I know that, this is why I did my solution...

Comment: What are "accurate results"? You haven't provide sample input or output. From what I can see, you shouldn't need to reshape the OpenCV Mat at all.

Comment: Why don't I need to reshape? The matlab code reshape the matrix to a 3 column matrix. I can provide input and outputm i don't understand what does this have to do with my question?  About how to create the same matlab code in c++?

Comment: How are we to determine if our code gets the same results? As for creating the same code, are you trying to reproduce the results you get from Matlab, or are you trying to reproduce the Matlab code line-for-line even when it makes getting the same results more complex?

Comment: i'm trying to get the same results as matlab. I have a working code in matlab and I want to convert it to openCV and get the same output from the same input.

Comment: @beaker I add the input data

Comment: I posted an answer. I wasn't able to test on your data, but it works ok on synthetic data. Please let me know if it works for you. (Also, next time please share data in some public place not requiring registration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
int newRows = accum1r.rows * accum1r.cols;
int dims[2] = {newRows,3};    
cv::Mat planes[] = {cv::Mat::zeros(newRows,1, CV_32F), cv::Mat::zeros(newRows,1, CV_32F), cv::Mat::zeros(newRows,1, CV_32F)};
cv::split(accum1r,planes);
planes[0] = planes[0].t();    
planes[0] = planes[0].reshape(1,2,dims);
planes[1] = planes[1].t();    
planes[1] = planes[1].reshape(1,2,dims);
planes[2] = planes[2].t();    
planes[2] = planes[2].reshape(1,2,dims);    
cv::merge(planes,3,accum1r);
```

can be rewritten as:

```
accum1r = accum1r.reshape(3, 1).t();
```

You can then get a `newRows x 3 x 1` matrix `timeMeanUnsorted` as in Matlab using:

```
cv::Mat timeMeanUnsorted = accum1r.reshape(1) / numberOfFrames;
```

If you want instead a `newRows x 1 x 3` (3 channel) matrix you can simply:

```
cv::Mat timeMeanUnsorted = accum1r / numberOfFrames;
```